# How do I create an empty map in Scala using a Tuple as a key?

Tags: scala, data-structures, hashmap, tuples

In Scala, a Map can be created using a `Tuple` as a key with the following:

```
val userMap = mutable.HashMap(
    (1, 25) -> "shankar",
    (2, 35) -> "ramesh")
```

How do I do this, but initialize it as an empty Map?

Theoretical syntax: But it does not seem work in the way described: it seems to create a HashMap with a key of Int and value of Int (because it is entered as pair) and then disregards String:

```
val userMap = mutable.HashMap[(Int, Int), String]()
```

Comment: @jwvh What about for a mutable Map?

Comment: Why it doesn't work?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It seems to create a HashMap with a key of Int and value of Int (because it is entered as pair) and then disregards String

Comment: What does "seems to" mean? Are you saying that the code fails, or just that you think it will fail? If it fails, what is the error? If it doesn't fail, delete the question!

Comment: Sorry, you can't just replace an existing question with a different one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What should I do then? It doesn't seem like a helpful question.

Comment: @swaplink: you could address the reason it was closed. There is a link in the banner that explains what kind of information your question should include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted code works fine. I have to guess that "it does not seem to work" because you're not using correct syntax to test the resulting `HashMap`.

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val userMap = mutable.HashMap[(Int, Int), String]()

userMap.update((1,1) , "blah")
userMap((1,1))  //res1: String = blah
```

You should post the code that actually doesn't work, along with the error, instead of trying to describe what "does not seem to work."

Comment: sorry, you are right does work. I was accessing it incorrectly and I thought that it was creating the wrong type for a bit.